# Android: is DataMap of Wearable.DataApi a persistent storage?

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I don't get if I could use it as a cloud storage between handheld and wearables or if it's just temporary.

[This](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi) is the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a `DataItem` (which can hold a serialized `DataMap`) into the `DataApi` it is persistent until some node deletes. It is kept in a database and shared between all devices.

Comment: hi, please, do you know if this is possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406728/android-wearable-api-how-to-pass-a-dynamic-list

Comment: a detail, if I turn off the devices, dataAPI will keep data for future synchronizations?

Comment: Yes. Think of DataItems as a replicated database, that wants to be the same on every device.